# Parse humanreadble time to milliseconds in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a string like, 4hours or 1day or 2months to milliseconds. But how would I do this efficiently without having to check if string.contains("h") etc....?

Node has [ms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms), would Java happen to have something similar?

Edit based on some responses: Yes the actual number can change, I gave 4 hours as an example but that can be 1, 2, 3, 5 etc. Same for the days and months. And yes they are directly next to each other. No spaces.
Example string: remind 1h Go to school
The output should be: 3 600 000 (milliseconds)

Comment: `java.time.Duration` (for things like hours) or `java.time.Period` (for civil time measures like days and months).

Comment: How does such a `String` really and exactly look? I hope a month won't have two n in it (like it does in your question text). Are the numeric values directly concatenated to the units or are they separated by an additional whitespace?

Comment: What is the expected result for months? They may be 28, 29, 30 or 31 days. Same question for days? They may be 23, 24 or 25 hours or even a value between those.

Comment: The `TimeUnit` class may help you to convert but it won't help parsing the string, unfortunately.

Comment: I believe that with [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) you can build a parser for the string. Not sure whether you want to start using Joda-Time at this point since it has been in maintenance mode for some years now.

Comment: We really need to see example strings, your best code, and expected output.

Comment: Edited my post to answer some questions

Comment: @Nick - Java doesn't have OOTB (Out-Of-The-Box) counterpart of Node [ms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms). You will need to define this function yourself in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can break this down into smaller pieces.

- Find such occurrences within the string;
- Take both the number part and the unit part and multiply their values in order to get the milliseconds.

To find the occurrences, you could use regular expressions. A regular expression like `(-?\d+)(h|days|min|sec)` would match such strings. Using `Pattern` and `Matcher` would help.

To convert to number to milliseconds, the units need to be mapped to a value matching the number of milliseconds for that unit. For example, `days` would map to 86400000.

Answer (score 0):

While it’s not built in, I don’t find it that bad.

```
    String[] exampleStrings = { "4hours", "1day", "2months" };
    for (String example : exampleStrings) {
        long millis;
        if (example.contains("hour") || example.contains("minute")
                || example.contains("second")) {
            String durationString = "PT" + unitToAbbreviation(example);
            Duration dur = Duration.parse(durationString);
            millis = dur.toMillis();
        } else {
            String periodString = "P" + unitToAbbreviation(example);
            Period per = Period.parse(periodString);
            Duration estimatedDuration = Duration.ZERO;
            for (TemporalUnit unit : per.getUnits()) {
                estimatedDuration = estimatedDuration.plus(
                        unit.getDuration().multipliedBy(per.get(unit)));
            }
            millis = estimatedDuration.toMillis();
        }
        System.out.format("%7s -> %10d milliseconds%n", example, millis);
    }
```

Output from this sample is:

> ```
>  4hours ->   14400000 milliseconds
>    1day ->   86400000 milliseconds
> 2months -> 5259492000 milliseconds
> ```

I have assumed that you have got only one number and one unit in the string. It may be `2months` or `1day` but not `2months1day`.

The length of days, months and years are inaccurate estimates since their real length vary. A month may be from 28 to 31 days, and a day may be from 23 to 25 hours.

I am using the following little auxiliary method for converting `4hours` into just `4h` as required by `Duration.parse()`:

```
String unitToAbbreviation(String withFullUnit) {
    return withFullUnit.replaceFirst("(\\d+[a-z])[a-z]*", "$1");
}
```

In case of a `Period` (a day-based rather than a time-based interval) I am iterating over the units that a `Period` supports — years, months and days. For each I am using `TemporalUnit.getDuration()` to get its estimated duration and `Period.get()` for getting the corresponing value. The call to `mulitpliedBy()` (don’t be surprised) multiplies the two.